# How to force nasm to address variables position-independent?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, ld

How to tell NASM (or LD) to process labels in a way that will make the segment position-independent?

The segment is going to be moved from one file to another and I want it to work properly on any position in any file.

Here is the code that illustrates my problem:

```
section .text
...
message: db 'hello world!',0x00
...
mov rax,SYSCALL_WRITE
mov rdi,STDOUT
mov rsi,message
mov rdx,13
syscall
```

In the orginal executable it prints "Hello world!", but when the segment is moved to another elf, it prints some random bytes.

Comment: Can You post some code ? As I might remember, Your code has to deal with that. 
Like stated here:
http://l4u-00.jinr.ru/usoft/WWW/www_debian.org/Documentation/elf/node21.html

Comment: Use `lea rsi, [rel message]` optionally add `default rel` at the top in which case you can do `lea rsi, [message]`.

Comment: Thanks Jester, it works!

Comment: @Hugo: I tried to address this and other issues in my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for other helpful stuff.

Comment: @PeterCordes I wasn't exactly sure what I was searching for so I didn't find your post, but it's fantastic, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Hugo: thanks.  I have plans to split out (into a separate question) the part about using LEA and how garbage in upper bits doesn't matter, since that's getting a bit off topic.  Feedback (on any part) from a person trying to understand this for the first time would be helpful.  It's been a while since I didn't already understand a lot of the background, so it can be hard to know what's obvious to other people (and what's useful and what's clutter.)